# How to check cpu usage of my application?

Tags: performance, sdk, lua, coronasdk

How can I check cpu usage of my application with Corona SDK?

the only thing i found on google is how to check memory usage

```
collectgarbage()
print( "MemUsage: " .. collectgarbage("count") )
local textMem = system.getInfo( "textureMemoryUsed" ) / 1000000
print( "TexMem:   " .. textMem )
```

Comment: In plain Lua there's `os.clock()`.

Comment: won't it show total cpu usage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, there is currently no way to check the cpu usage of your application in Corona SDK.