# How can I discover CPU usage of my application in Android (programmatically)?

Tags: android, performance, android-ndk, cpu, power-management

**Is there any way to find out CPU usage of my Android application programmatically?** I'm aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17632091/how-to-check-cpu-usage-of-my-application) question already, but it is about Corona SDK.

Note that I want to do this on non-root devices.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found a way to calculate the CPU usage of a process by PID. According to the [doc](https://linux.die.net/man/5/proc), the `/proc/[pid]/stat` file contains status information about the process. So we can parse this file to get the following members:

- utime %lu
- stime %lu

[Check this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420426/how-to-calculate-the-cpu-usage-of-a-process-by-pid-in-linux-from-c) to get more information about the `/proc/[pid]/stat` file and the way to [parse it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4410209/8460132).

Also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4310039/user-cpu-time-vs-system-cpu-time) is a relevant question about `utime` and `stime`.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure about programmatically, but you can use **Android profiler** to achieve the same.

> 1. Run your application, either in a physical device or emulator (doesn't matter here)
> 2. When the application is running, you will see a **Profile** tab in the toolbar

If you don't see a **Profile** tab, you can access the same using **Run > Profile 'app'**

**Edit**
[Check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1058991/7944759)

**Edit 2**
You can use **firebase performance monitoring** for runtime data collection about performance. [Follow this link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/perf-mon/get-started-android)

Comment: I know that, but I want to find out CPU usage of my Android application programmatically.

Comment: Saurabh, That link is about the device not the application itself.

Comment: great. Thank you. @Saurabh Mishra